# My parents refuse to accept a marriage because they don’t approve of the family

Tags: nikah, sin, family, curse

My parents have completely refused the guy I would like to marry because they believe he comes from a “bad” family.

To cut a long story short, our families know each other from when I was very young. Although no one will go into any detail, I feel there may have been some friction between them when me and him were very small. To add to this, one of the family members had been to jail in the past and this is the only basis they have to go off.

However as a result of this, my family has painted him out to be a terrible person never having met him. Even though he had absolutely nothing to with it. They refuse to meet him, and refuse to give him a chance for no reason, simply because he is part of this same family tree. His immediate family is well practicing, and his mother is also a devout Muslim.

My mother has cursed me, him and his whole family. My father has gone as far as contacting his family to tell them how much of a bad family they are, he has sworn at them and so on.

They also don’t feel he is ‘fit’ to look after me simply because he is also a student and the same age as me (which is not grounds to deny someone either)

I feel as though I have been dealt with unfairly, and feel he has been so severely judged over no action of his own. While my family pride themselves in being good Muslims, I couldn’t understand how they could be so judgemental and hypocritical and to be honest I am not sure what to do.

I never want to displease my parents, however they have not taken any care in trying to understand me at all. They only spoke to me with their minds made up, having no room to listen to anything I had to say. They have not provided any solid basis to reject him (their judgements are purely based on assumption and no tangible facts, as he is a practicing muslim) and yet, they have painted me out to be a disrespectful and disobedient child for fighting for him, and wanting to do things the halal way (get married).

Am I wrong to fight for him?
Does my mothers curse hold any weight?

I am just scared and don’t know what to do.

Comment: We are not a peer support group. Questions should be about general teachings of Islam, not asking for opinions on personal disputes. According to Islam parents must be obeyed and the have a right to decide who gets married with their daughter, and are responsible for choosing a suitable match. Whether or not their judgement is correct can not be checked by the people on this forum, let alone without hearing their reasons firsthand.

Answer (score -1):

Try having an imam talk to yor parents. I know this strategy worked for someone else. You could also have his family and yours sit together and talk it out with or without the imam, but I think in your case, havig the imam there would be helpful.